# C++ streams can't tell where one string ends and the next begins?

Tags: c++, stream, ifstream, ofstream

I'm writing a string and an int to an ofstream, then trying to read that back with an ifstream. I would expect the string to be null terminated, so the stream should know where the string stops and where the int begins. But that's not happening -- when I read it back in, it treats the int as part of the string. How do I avoid that?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string tempFile("tempfile.out");
    std::ofstream outStream(tempFile); //Tried this both with text 
    //and with ::bin but get same results

    std::string outStr1("Hello");
    int outInt1 = 5;
    std::string outStr2("Goodbye");

    outStream << outStr1 << outInt1 << outStr2;
    outStream.close();

    std::ifstream inStream(tempFile);  //Tried this both with text 
    //and with ::bin but get same results
    std::string inStr1, inStr2;
    int inInt1;
    inStream >> inStr1; //this reads a string that concats all 
    //my prev values together!
    inStream >> inInt1; //doesn't do what I want since the int was 
    //already read as part of the string
    inStream >> inStr2; //doesn't do what I want 
}
```

How can I make it separate the string and the int instead of combining them into a single string?

Comment: There are no strings or ints on the stream. If you want to distinguish things, you need to devise and use a format to do that. Comma separated values and XML are 2 approaches. There are others.

Comment: A stream isn't a protocol, it's just a pipe you can send bytes down.

Comment: But the in-memory string has a null terminator. Does that stream not save that null terminator?

Comment: A std::string may contain embedded nulls. Those nulls will be output. A final null terminator is part of the implementation, but not part of the data of the string and will not be output. You need to use some method to separate fields in your stream. There are many approaches to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add newline to separate the strings

```
outStream << outStr1 << std::endl << outInt1 << std::endl << outStr2;
```

> But why is the newline needed? The string is null-terminated, so
>   shouldn't c++ write that null character to the byte stream? If so,
>   then why is a newline needed?

It doesn't have to be newline though newline would work for you...

std::string doesn't necessarily have to be nul terminated. It has `size` and should be treated like an array/vector of characters. You can write the nul to the stream if the str is constructed as:

```
std::string outStr1{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0};
```

while

```
 std::string s("OK");
```

constructs a string with size 2.

When you read data from a stream, it needs to know the **rule** to extract bytes and convert to the type expected. Basically if you read a string from the stream it needs to know when to end the string. The simple rule is if it reaches a space(`std::isspace()`), the string terminates. Here space means whitespace, tab, line break, etc.

Say if you want to extract an integer, it should stop when reaching a char that is not legal in a integer notation, like 'z'.

To fully understand this, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedInputFunction is a good start.

Comment: Tactical note: '\n' is far less expensive than `std::endl` due to the stream flush built into `std::endl`.

Comment: But why is the newline needed? The string is null-terminated, so shouldn't c++ write that null character to the byte stream? If so, then why is a newline needed?